# button_to changing state of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to change the state of an object either:

1) by the user clicking on a button in the /view/matchdays/index.html.erb:

```
<%= button_to "End Matchday", {:action => :end_matchday}, :class => "push-9" %>
```

2) or if 2 days has passed by. Each time a user goes to the index it will running end_of_matchday_check to see if this is correct.

matchdays_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    @matchdays = Matchday.all
    @current_matchday = Matchday.last
    # Runs a check on the last matchday whether user can edit the matchday
    end_of_matchday_check unless Matchday.all.empty?
  end

  def end_matchday
    @current_matchday = Matchday.last
    @current_matchday.update_attributes(:ended => true)
    redirect_to matchdays_path
  end

  private

# Returns true if the last matchday has exceeded 2 days = the allowable editing priod.
  def end_of_matchday_check
      @current_matchday = Matchday.last
      unless @current_matchday.ended? 
        @current_matchday.update_attributes(:ended => true) if @current_matchday.created_at + 2.days > Time.now
      end
  end
```

However I keep running into this problem (Develop log):

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ended
```

But if I comment out the attr_accessible line or add :ended to it, it will work. However each time I visit the index page it will change matchday.ended to true every time I create a new matchday object.

Matchday.rb:

```
attr_accessible :name, :best_of, :description
```

Any idea as to why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def end_matchday
  @current_matchday = Matchday.last
  @current_matchday.ended = true
  @current_matchday.save
  redirect_to matchdays_path
end
```

or

```
def end_matchday
  @current_matchday = Matchday.last
  @current_matchday.update_attribute( :ended, true )
  redirect_to matchdays_path
end
```

**UPD**

ok.

You should ramove all `update_attributes(:ended => true)` to `update_attribute(:ended, true)` or `@object.ended = true; @object.save`

**SUMMARY**

```
 def index
    @matchdays = Matchday.all
    @current_matchday = Matchday.last
    # Runs a check on the last matchday whether user can edit the matchday
    end_of_matchday_check unless Matchday.all.empty?
  end

  def end_matchday
    @current_matchday = Matchday.last
    @current_matchday.update_attribute(:ended, true)
    redirect_to matchdays_path
  end

  private

  # Returns true if the last matchday has exceeded 2 days = the allowable editing priod.
  def end_of_matchday_check
      @current_matchday = Matchday.last
      unless @current_matchday.ended? 
        @current_matchday.update_attribute(:ended, true) if @current_matchday.created_at + 2.days > Time.now
      end
  end
```

Comment: That did not work because it doesn't call the end_matchday action unless the user clicks on the button. I did some puts statements and found out it automatically goes to the end_of_matchday_check and changes the ended attribute to true! By default its ended should be false unless it has been 2 days.

Comment: see my update. you should change all your `update_attributes` to `update_attribute`

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. My

```
@current_matchday.created_at + 2.days > Time.now
```

logic was wrong. It should be

```
@current_matchday.created_at + 2.days < Time.now
```

< instead of >. The current time should be more than 2 days then it will change the attribute to true and not change it within 2 days.

**Update**

I applied flOOr's solution first by changing

```
 @current_matchday.update_attributes(:ended => true)
```

to

```
@current_matchday.update_attribute(:ended, true)
```

After applying his solution another one popped up and I wrote about it mistakenly thinking it was the solution.

Sorry for the mixup flOOr and thanks again, much appreciated :)

Comment: wasn't your problem in mass-asign? `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ended`

Comment: Yes it was see the update above. Again sorry for the mix up for what its worth I marked your solution as the correct answer.